# search for a string in a file which is delimited and then print the string until the next delimiter is reached in linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have below text in a file

```
1|2|SID1=/some/path|SID2=/some/path|4|5
1|2|SID1=/some/path|tel|path|SID2=/some/path|6|5|ord|til
1|2|SID1=/some/path|id1|id2|id3|SID2=/some/path|4|8|dea
```

In Linux, how do I seach for SID1 and SID2 in each line and print only till the next delimiter, so the output should be

```
SID1=/some/path SID2=/some/path
SID1=/some/path SID2=/some/path
SID1=/some/path SID2=/some/path
```

Comment: I am trying the below code `cat filename | awk -F "|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i ~ /SID*/){print $i}}}'` but its not working

Comment: Define "not working". That looks like it should print each field of each line on its own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print join " ", /SID[12]=[^|]*/g' file.txt
```

Explanation: Perl reads the file line by line (-n). All parts of the line containing SID followed by 1 or 2 followed by = followed by anything but | are printed with a space between them.

Comment: This'll grab fields like `|BOO SID1=/some/path|` too though won't it?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes. If they exist, and SID can appear at the very beginning of the line, use something like  `/(?:^|\|)(SID[12]=[^|]*)/g`.

Comment: Thank you so much perl command worked..I will try awk as well

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing a better solution but this works

Oneline:

```
awk -F'|' '{a=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^SID[[:digit:]]*=/) { printf "%s%s", a?OFS:(NR>1)?ORS:"", $i; a++ }}} END {print ""}' file
```

Explained:

```
awk -F'|' '{
    # Reset our field tracking.
    a=0

    # Loop over all the fields in the line.
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        # If the current field starts with 'SID#=' then
        if ($i ~ /^SID[[:digit:]]*=/) {
            # Print out the field with the appropriate separator.
            # When we have 'a' set we are in a line and want to print out a
            # leading OFS. Otherwise if this is not the first line we want to
            # print out a leading ORS. Otherise do nothing.
            printf "%s%s", a?OFS:(NR>1)?ORS:"", $i
            # Set our field tracking.
            a=1
        }
    }
}

END {
    # Print out the final newline.
    print ""
}' file
```